# Access history of a field in Nintex Workflow 2013

Tags: 2013

We have a list with a "Append Changes to Existing Text" multiline text field in it. As far as I have understood, the changing texts of the field are stored in versions of the item and are then displayed cumulative.

In an Nintex 2013 list workflow, is there a way I can retrieve all values of the field from the current item, so I can display/mail them cumulative?